# Generate HttpWebRequest code from Browser Network capture

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Are there any tools that like fiddler capture the http requests but also help me generate .net HttpWebRequest code?

I'm replicating requests with HttpWebRequest and on some are failing, it would be easier if I used a tool for that, and as fiddler captures the traffic and some toolgenerated the code it would be way easier, anyone knows such tool?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to have a Fiddler plugin for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the "Requests-to-Code" Fiddler extension already exists; get it here: http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code

Comment: Still trying to test it, but this is exactly what I wanted! I'm wondering how can I get the ASP.NET Session Id from my first request and pass it correclty to the second one, but this is a whole different question!

Comment: Typically, what you'd want to do there is attach the same CookieContainer to each of the HTTPWebRequests you create/send.